# How to change classic Pivot Table layout using xlwings?

Tags: xlwings

I want to change Pivot Table layout to classic layout
In excel the path is as below
Pivot Table Option -> Display -> click classic layout

How can I do that using xlwings?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The very simple code below solves the problem:

```
PivotTable.RowAxisLayout(1)
```